# Are text inputs submitting the form when the return key is pressed a guaranteed behavior?

Tags: html, standards, web-standards

On Chrome and Firefox, a form is submitted if the return key is pressed inside any text input inside the form.

Is this behaviour part of the standard?

Comment: If you have a submit input or button, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this behavior is not required. I’m afraid it isn’t even *mentioned* in the HTML 4.01 specification, though this is probably just an oversight.

But it is very common behavior and needs to be taken into account: users may well accidentally submit form data by pressing Enter, when they still intended to continue filling it out.

There are some browser differences, e.g. IE 9 does not do anything when Enter is pressed in a field provided that a) there are more than one text input fields there and b) there is no submit button. On older versions, condition a) was sufficient, and this was more or less the original idea (the feature was meant to make it easy to use very simple search forms without causing confusion).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is default behavior.
**[edit]** I should qualify, this is for pretty much everything IE7 and up. I do know that some older browsers (Netscape) may not have done this. But for today's browser landscape, yes this is standard.